# I am displaying all users pictures and education on a page, how do I just remove the current user from the list?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Since the current user doesn't care about his info only the info other the others, he must be excluded from the list. I have read that core data fetchrequest can be used for this, but I am not sure how and where to incorporate NSFetchRequest.

I have tries using NSFetchRequest at various places but I get Class methods may only be declared on a type errors.

///upstream

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return people.count

}

public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblName.text = person.Education

    if let PhotoPosts = person.PhotoPosts {
        let url = URL(string: PhotoPosts)
        immy.sd_setImage(with: url)
    }

    return cell
}
```

////downstream

```
refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");

refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

    if snapshot.childrenCount>0{

        self.people.removeAll()

        for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
            let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as? String
            let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts)
                self.people.append(peopl)

        }
        self.table.reloadData()
        print(snapshot)

    }

})
```

////different file that gets to above file

```
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
if Education.text == "" || {
    print ("missing")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Missing Field.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
else if takenImage == nil{

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Missing Photo.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

else {

    databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Education").setValue(self.Education.text!)

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tohome", sender: nil)

}
```

The final result would be all users except the current one displayed.

Comment: Without looking too closely as the code, let me propose a simple solution. Assuming you're working with Firebase authentication, each user has a uid associated with their account. Also assuming you're storing users in the /people node with the uid as the key to each child node. As you read in the people node (or iterate over the child nodes), if the key being read in is equal to the current authenticated users uid, ignore it and don't add it to the array.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I use firebase and my database looks exactly like that. How would you code a line to ignore that uid? I am guessing it should go in either the refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people") part or this part:    let immy = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    let person: Userx = people[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblName.text = person.Education

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP would like to read in all users stored in a /people node but ignore this users info. Assuming that Firebase Authentication is being used and that each child node within the /people node has a key of that users uid. The structure would be

```
people
   uid_0 // firebase uid
      name: "Captain Oveur"
      email: "oveur@machogrande.com"
   uid_1
      name: "Mr. Unger"
      email: "unger@machogrande.com"
   uid_2
      name: "Mr. Dunn"
      email: "dunn@machogrande.com"
```

and let's say Mr. Dunn is logged in and is the current user. The following code reads in all users in the people node and prints them to console, but ignores the currently authenticated users information.

```
func fetchAllUsersExceptCurrentUser() {
    let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid //Mr. Dunn's uid
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if user.key != thisUsersUid { //do not add this users info to the array
                let userObject = user.value as! [String: Any]
                let name = userObject["name"] as? String ?? "No name"
                let email = userObject["email"] as? String ?? "no email"
                print(name, email) //add the data to the array
            }
        }
    })
}
```

note that self.ref is a reference to *my* Firebase root node. You would substitute yours in.

Comment: Thanks. Currently have two errors at let name: Value of optional type '[String : AnyObject]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[String : AnyObject]' and Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: do you know why that might be?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo - my code is `let userObject = user.value as! [String: Any]` and yours is `as? [String : AnyObject]`. If you are telling XCode the dictionary is an optional, you need to handle it - which is what XCode is telling you. I am guaranteeing it will exist, so using `as!`

Comment: I found another small error. Works perfectly now. Thanks!